# pycharm ругается на ctx :Unresolved reference 'сtx'

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import context_managers
import sqlite3
from config import settings

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',intents = discord.Intents.all(), test_guilds=[1131257354416029856])
client.remove_command('help')

connection=sqlite3.connect('discord.db')
cursor=connection.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    name TEXT,
    id INT,
    cash BIGINT,
    rep INT,
    lvl INT
    )''')
    connection.commit()
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
                connection.commit()
            else:
                pass
    print('bot connected')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
        connection.commit()
    else:
        pass
@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    print(hi)
@client.slash_command()
async def _balance(ctx,member: discord.Member=None):
    if member is None:
        await сtx.send(embed=discord.Embed(
            description=f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute('SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id ={}'.format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}:catcoin:**"""
        ))
    else:
        description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{member.id}** составляет **{cursor.execute('SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id ={}'.format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]}:catcoin:**"""
    print('done')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print('1111')
client.run(settings['TOKEN'])
```

вот что выдает pycharm:

[image]

[image]

как мне исправить это?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Укажите, на какой конкретно строке показывает эту ошибку. Ну и в целом, код работает, или при выполнении кода тоже ошибка возникает?

Comment: Ошибка из-за того, что в "заголовке" функции у вас ctx правильно написано, а там где ошибку показывает - русская с вместо латинской c. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VRsE.png